# How to display message payload data in template

Tags: django, python-3.x, gmail-api

I'm getting the messages from Gmail I am unable to display the message body in a template.

I got encoded data from payload after I decoded it using `base64`, after I stored this in the dictionary in python after I am displaying in template it is displaying the payload data as a string data.

```
msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(msg['payload']['body']['data'].encode('UTF8'))
return render(request,'emailapp/index.html',{'msgdecddata':msg_str})
```

Need to execute payload data in template.